# Insert data into Database using php PDO

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to create a "registration" form using php and mysql. The registration form asks for username and password. If any field is empty, it will let the user know which one. If the username is in use, it will also let the user know.

I know the connection to the database is ok, because I created a user that was I manually added into the database.

The strange thing is that my code is working in Cloud9. But, it wont work on a VM instance installed on google cloud.

In cloud9, it adds the user into the DB. In the google instance, it wont.

Can anyone check this and tell me what I;m doing wrong?

Thanks.

```
<?php
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $display = $_POST['display'];



        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb","root",NULL);
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :username");
        $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
        $stmt->execute();

        if($stmt->rowCount() == 0 and $username != null and $password != null){
            $insert = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username,password) VALUES(:username, :password)");
            $insert->bindParam(':username', $username);
            $insert->bindParam(':password', $password);
            $insert->execute();
            echo ("The user ".$username. " has been created.");
```

Comment: Any errors in the log?

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.

Comment: Does it echo the message saying that the user was created?

Comment: You don't tell us what is going wrong. What is the error message? You should check return values from `prepare()` and `execute()`, and there's no need to bind parameters with PDO. I hope you don't seriously have no password on your root user!

Comment: No error logs. When I try to create a new user, it just says "the user blablabla has been created", after that I check the DB and it is not there.

[I do have a password, and a username for the DB. I just change that info for this post.]

I know the DB connection works, because it does check if the username exist. As mentioned, I tried to create a user that I manually added into the DB, and it does returns that the username is in use.

Comment: Got it solved!.

The reason was the following. I designed the DB to have 3 fields (the users table) [ID, username, password]

So, as you can see in the code, I was not taking into consideration the ID. That is the reason why it did not load the new user into the DB. The ID was missing.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, before all u need to check

- if username and password is not empty because if username is empty i
  cant make query valid to select username
- check if username is in use
- if username not in use, insert data into database

script

```
<?php

// error_reporting on
error_reporting(1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
// i commented $display variable because i don't see that u using it anywhere
//$display = $_POST['display'];

// database connection
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb","root","");

// query
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :username");
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
$stmt->execute();

// check if username and password is not empty
if ($username != '' && $password != '')
{
    // check if username is in use
    if($stmt->rowCount() > 1)
    {
        echo "Username in use, please choose another one.";
    }
    else
    {
        $insert = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username,password) VALUES(:username, :password)");
        $insert->bindParam(':username', $username);
        $insert->bindParam(':password', $password);
        $insert->execute();

        // if last inserted id is true
        if ($dbh->lastInsertId())
        {
            echo "The user ".$username. " has been created.";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "User not registered, please try again.";
        }
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Please enter username and password.";
}
?>
```

Comment: why negative vote ? code don't works or fail ? really